# large amount of data in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am designing an application that require to store data in one Sqlite table in android 4.2+ and regularly fetch some of the data among them. Maximum amount of data could be near 100K records, and the number of columns of each record is 6 String and Integer. I want to know how can I efficiently read some data from this table of 100K records? (I want to use the application on the tablet with 1GB of RAM and a Quad core cpu 1.2GH). If it is not possible, could archiving some old data make the performance better? I can create an archive table and move old data (low rate accessed data) into this new table

thanks in advance

Clarification---- is searching among 100K records too expensive for a mobile device with mentioned config? can search be done in less than 2 sec? has anyone similar experience for searching among thousands of record in a mobile device?

Comment: What sort of "search" do you mean?

Comment: For enhanced performances, set **indexes** on your `search` and your `join` fields, if any.

Comment: simple select with id or some features (columns) and i don't have nay join. it is a simple SELECT query but among 100K records

Answer (score 1):

A query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeColumn = ?
```

can be executed very efficiently if `SomeColumn` is indexed, either because it is the PRIMARY KEY, or because you [created an index](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can  make  a data base of Strings and integers  as much as you need  and search would not take such long time 
 but notice that your values must be characters not picture or byte data 
if you want use such data you must store them on sd card and use the address of that data 
You also can make your data base  in your pc by  sqlmanager  and push it in your app

Here you can find a sample code of sqlilte .

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example

Comment: Merc amir, i know how to work with sqlite in android and i was just looking for performance in case of 100k records